# Is there a neater way to analyse the AuthenticationException for the error code?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Is there a neater way to check the `javax.naming.AuthenticationException` (or spring) for the main failure reason? The different errors are desciribed in [LDAP Wiki (Binding Errors)](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors).

The AuthenticationException provides no sufficient API to determine easily the error code. The only content is the exception message.

```
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: 
 LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, 
 comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, vece]
```

The identifing block is the "data 773" – standing for the error `ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE`. But it feels very odd to me to check for `message.contains("data 773")`! Is there any better way to check the error code?

---

The snippet which throws the `AuthenticationException` is written with the `org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource`.

```
InitialLdapContext context = (InitialLdapContext) contextFactory
                     .getReadWriteContext(principal, password);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the only way I've seen it handled because the failure codes produced by the LDAP service I have experience with (Active Directory) always encodes the failure code in the message.  Don't feel too bad even though it isn't a nice way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no better implementation for this. You could try providing a whole translation for the ldap error codes in an external file and use them to translate.