# How can I extract an "error code" number from a JNDI NamingException?

Tags: java, exception, ldap, jndi, apacheds

I have some code that proxies LDAP messages.
The code implements handlers of ApacheDS by calling LDAP servers using JNDI.
When an error is returned from the LDAP server, JNDI reports it as an  javax.naming.NamingException (or subclass) like:

```
  AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

On the other hand we need to return an answer to the client through the ApacheDS sink using an error code enum:

```
  ResultCodeEnum resultCodeEnum = ResultCodeEnum.getResultCode(errorCode);
  ldapResult.setResultCode(resultCodeEnum);
```

How can I extract the "error code" number from the JNDI  javax.naming.NamingException?
(of course I can always parse the 'error code' from NamingException.explanation, if a number is found in explanation, but I'm looking for a library solution)

Comment: I don't think there is anything standard. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421643/is-there-a-neater-way-to-analyse-the-authenticationexception-for-the-error-code

Comment: Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/exceptions.html

Comment: In case of SqlException it has e.getErrorCode() method to retrieve the error code. What is the Exception class you have ? Does it not have some thing similar to that ?

Comment: I have a javax.naming.NamingException (or subclass)

Comment: (edited the title and content to say NamingException)

Answer (score 1):

You need get exception message from exception using `e.getMessage()` this will give you  exception string as `AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]`

```
try {
      // you stuff here .....
} catch (NamingException e) {
  int errCode= getErrorCode(e.getMessage());
}
```

using Java regex to get/extract error code form exception string

```
 private int getErrorCode(final String exceptionMsg)
    {
        String pattern="-?\\d+";
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher  m=p.matcher(exceptionMsg);
        if (m.find()) {
            return Integer.valueOf(m.group(0));
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Of course I can always parse the 'error code' from NamingException.explanation, if a number is found in explanation, but I'm looking for a library solution

Comment: You can make custom exception class(LDAPException extend NamingException) int you custom exception class you neeed message, errorcode code properties and getter/setter, throw LDAPException to your client code and catch it, then get it e.getErrorCode(). INside Error code you extract error code. this once. there is not need of libaray

Comment: My code does not throw the exceptions, it calls LDAP servers using JNDI. When an error is returned from the LDAP server, JNDI reports it as an javax.naming.NamingException (or subclass)

Comment: NamingException a runtime exception, if not then write a generic method in a util class extract the error code from exception, where you are handling exception that place jsut getErrorCode() method.

Comment: "extract the error code from exception" - that's the question